# <c:import> getting old (probably cached) html content

Tags: jsp, caching

I am hitting a URL in a JSP thru the tag:
<'c:import url="${pageContext.request.scheme}://${pageContext.request.serverName}:${pageContext.request.serverPort}/${pageContext.request.contextPath}/html/temp.html" var="content" />

I am getting the html content properly. Now, I change the html content for temp.html but the JSP is rendering the old html content. Instead, if I make a direct call to the http://servername.com/html/temp.html, I get the newly modified content.

The htmls are hosted on Akamai servers and I've made sure that the Akamai cache is getting refreshed.

Any clue why does this happen? Is there any other kind of proxy/server cache which is retrieving the old content?

Thanks,
Narain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a query string with some random value. E.g. a timestamp.

```
<jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date" />

<c:import url="/${pageContext.request.contextPath}/html/temp.html?${now.time}" var="content" />
```

*Note that I stripped unnecessary noise from your `url`.*

Comment: That worked suberbly. But still I could not understand what makes it work with just a query string? I would be thankful if you could help me on this.

Comment: This way the URL becomes different everytime, so there is no risk that it will be loaded from the cache.

Comment: Ok thanks. Actually, the static content is hosted on Akamai servers. This particular problem, was reproducible only on staging.server.com whereas on origin.staging.server.com, it used to work fine. The akamai cache was cleared many times. Any clue how does staging and origin servers cache the content in different ways?

Answer (score 0):

could be your browser (try ctrl + f5) to do a forced refresh on your page with the import in.